# Separate filename.jpg from a string

Tags: php, find, preg-replace

I've got a field in my MySQL table with several params. I want to just get the **filename.jpg** or **filename.gif** as a new variable.

Here's the info in the table (Joomla banner module)

```
$string = '{"imageurl":"images\/banners\/foo.gif","width":"","height":"","alt":""}';

$theimage = find(gif or jpg, $string); // Or something.. :-)
```

Comment: Have you tried doing that or you expect us to write the code for you? ;/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/json_decode) method to decode the string and convert it into an object. And then use the [pathInfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) method to get the extension as shown below.

```
<?php

$string = '{"imageurl":"images\/banners\/foo.gif","width":"","height":"","alt":""}';
$obj = json_decode($string);
$names = pathInfo($obj->imageurl);
echo $names['extension']; //gif
echo $names['basename']; //foo.gif
echo $names['filename']; //foo

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex:

```
$input_lines = '{"imageurl":"images\/banners\/foo.gif","width":"","height":"","alt":""}';
preg_match_all("/[A-Za-z0-9]+\.(gif|jpg)/", $input_lines, $output_array);
print_r($output_array);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => foo.gif
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => gif
    )

)
```